What is the difference between record and expression in the prometheus rules config?
From the rules documentation:
record: The name of the time series to output to. Must be a valid metric name.
expr: The PromQL expression to evaluate. Every evaluation cycle this is evaluated at the current time, and the result recorded as a new set of time series with the metric name as given by 'record'.
I understand the record as the name of the rule, and the expression as the PromQL statement to evaluate.
But when I go to the rules tab, they appears as two separate links, and the graphs are different:


What is the reason?
Here my config files:
metrics.rules.yml
groups:
  - name: wellboreddms_rules
    rules:
    # HTTP request rate (number of requests per time unit)
    - record: number_of_requests_per_time
      expr: increase(http_requests_total{group="wellbore_ddms"}[30s])
    # HTTP response times (average)
    - record: avg_response_time
      expr: rate(http_request_duration_seconds_sum[30s]) / rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count[30s])

prometheus.yml
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s

  # Attach these labels to any time series or alerts when communicating with
  # external systems (federation, remote storage, Alertmanager).
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'codelab-monitor'

rule_files:
  - "metrics.rules.yml"

scrape_configs:

  - job_name: 'wdms'
    scrape_interval: 3s
    metrics_path: /api/os-wellbore-ddms/metrics
    scheme: http
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['api:8080']
        labels:
          group: 'wellbore_ddms'


Links are different because one is showing you a values of the metric created by recording rule, and another - original results of the query used as expression.
If everything is correct, they suppose to have same results. In your case result differs because your rules are erroneous.
Let's take for example first rule number_of_requests_per_time. See, your rule records increase of the metric over 30 seconds. But since you didn't specify evaluation interval (neither local interval, nor global evaluation_interval) default value of 1m is used. This means that you record changes of the original metric only during second 30 seconds of each minute, and ignore changes during first 30 seconds.

so taking the first rule as an example, if I understood correctly, I should set an interval that match the increase of the metric (30s) like:
metrics.rules.yml
groups:

name: wellbore_ddms_rules
interval: 30s
rules:...

and an evaluation interval of 30s too in the global config:
#prometheus.yml
global:
scrape_interval: 15s
evaluation_interval: "30s"
right?

@SantiagoOrtizCeballos, one of them is enough. evaluation_interval is used if interval is not set in a specific rule group.
